# How do typedef-ed pointers work

Tags: c, typedef

```
typedef int* ptr_t;
int target;
const ptr_t a = &target;
*a = 6;            //OK
a = &target;       //<- error: assignment of read-only variable ‘a’
```

Clearly, the pointer is constant, and not the value pointed. This is in contrast if a #define was used.

What are the rules for applying modifiers to pointers, declared in a typedef?

For a practical example, consider the code
    `void (**foo)(void);`

- How would one go about typedef-ing a type, that qualifies the top-level pointer as const(e.g. pointing to a hardware location), the next pointer as volatile (e.g. modifiable by independent hardware) pointer to a function?
- `typedef void (**foo)(void)` If this is the fixed declaration that we have to work with, ow d owe do the above operation in the source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section 6.7.5.1 of the C standard describes the difference. It gives as an example:

```
const int *ptr_to_constant;
int *const constant_ptr;
```

And says:

> The contents of any object pointed to by `ptr_to_constant` shall not be
>   modified through that pointer, but `ptr_to_constant` itself may be
>   changed to point to another object. Similarly, the contents of the `int`
>   pointed to by `constant_ptr` may be modified, but `constant_ptr` itself
>   shall always point to the same location.

Finally, point 4 in that section describes the use of typedefs.

> The declaration of the constant pointer `constant_ptr` may be clarified
>   by including a definition for the type ‘‘pointer to int’’.

```
  typedef int *int_ptr;
  const int_ptr constant_ptr;
```

> declares `constant_ptr` as an object that has type ‘‘const-qualified
>   pointer to int’’.

Answer (score 3):

The rule is:

- `typedef` is not pure textual replacement like a macro.
- The declaration is not parsed to see that there is a pointer involved in typedef
- The *cv qualifier* applies to the synonym you created with typedef i.e: `int *`.

So,

```
typedef int* ptr_t;
const ptr_t a = &target;
```

is not same as:

```
const int* a;
```

but it is same as:

```
int *const a;
```

Put in words, First declares a const constant pointer to int, not pointer to constant int as in second.

As you just noticed from your example,
It is a bad practice to `typedef` pointers because it reduces the code readability and intuitiveness. It ie very easy to create bugs while using typedef for pointers. It is best to avoid it.